# how to scaffold the database triggers

Tags: sql-server, c#

I'm trying to find a way to include table triggers when reverse-engineering the database. but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I'm using SQLserver and .netCore 3.1 with efcore.

and each time I scaffold the dbcontext , the triggers aren't scaffolded.

Here's my command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server={server};database={database};user={user};password={password}" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --project  "{project}" --output-dir "Models" --force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to scaffold **Triggers**, and it doesn't make much sense since they are a database specific type of object (not sure what they could map to in C#?). They don't directly describe the database model, as opposed to **Tables**, **Columns**, and **Keys**. What is your end goal that you wanted to scaffold the **Triggers**?

Please see [Entity Framework Core - Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) documentation for more information.

Particularly the **How it works** section details what is scaffolded from the database:

> Reverse engineering starts by reading the database
> schema. It reads information about tables, columns, constraints, and
> indexes.
>
> Next, it uses the schema information to create an EF Core model.
> Tables are used to create entity types; columns are used to create
> properties; and foreign keys are used to create relationships.
>
> Finally, the model is used to generate code. The corresponding entity
> type classes, Fluent API, and data annotations are scaffolded in order
> to re-create the same model from your app.

Comment: oh you're right! I totally missed that point!
I'm moving my work from a computer to another, and I wanted to create a migration so that I can create the db tables and data on the new computer. and I thought this was an easy way! looks like I'm going to script the database now. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AtaaAub No problem! Yes, it's better to use the built in database features to actually move a database. Three out of box options are: 1) Script the entire database (data and schemas), as you mentioned; 2) Create a full backup and restore it on the new machine; 3) Generate a BACPAC file of the database (which will include the data and schemas)